# can't install ruby on rails w/ mac 10.5.8

Tags: ruby, installation

I have an older mac mini (v10.5.8) I would like to put the latest version of rails on.

`gem update --system` gives me "no such file to load"

`gem install rubygems-update` gives me the same thing as above

So I manually downloaded from rubygems.org/pages/download and extracted the tar then tried running `ruby setup.rb` but that gives me...

```
./lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in 'gem_original_require': no such file to load -- stringio (LoadError)
```

...so I'm stuck now..I'm not sure where to go from here...running `ruby -v` gives me "1.8.7 (2008-05-31 patchlevel 0"

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the system ruby, you should try to use [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/) to install a recent version of Ruby:

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled --ruby=1.9.3
```

Or, if you want more control

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
$ rvm get head
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

Either way, make sure you run

```
$ rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

Note that you may have to install XCode and XCode Command-Line Tools before all of this. Note also that you probably shouldn't use `sudo`... just have it install ruby for your user.

Comment: looks like it may work, but now I have "BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 3.2.17(1)-release)".  Know how to quickly update bash?  Googling "update bash" is like finding how to skin a cat.

Comment: you can install bash with [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) or [macports](http://www.macports.org/)... make sure you read the [full installation instructions](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) for homebrew because you're on 10.5... for macports, use [the 10.5 installer](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.1.3-10.5-Leopard.dmg). incidentally, having macports or homebrew will probably make your life easier in general :)

Comment: (also, if you're on 10.5 because you don't want lion or mountain lion, i would say that upgrading to 10.6 is safe... the big changes don't come til 10.7)

Comment: It's an old mac mini (circa 2005) that errors on any updates after 10.5.  Believe me, I really want upgrade it!